# Update MySQL query not working from Lynda Tutorial

Tags: php, mysql

I'm following the PHP tutorial from Lynda. I got to the update part of the tutorial but my code won't execute the page simply reloads. I can't seem to figure it out.

```
$id = mysql_prep($_GET['subj']);
$menu_name = mysql_prep($_POST['menu_name']);
$position = mysql_prep($_POST['position']);
$visible = mysql_prep($_POST['visible']);

$query = "UPDATE 'widget_corp' . 'subjects' SET
    menu_name = '{$menu_name}',
    position = {$position},
    visible = {$visible}
    WHERE id = $id";
```

Comment: running that query would be a start `mysql_query($query);` and switch to a mysqli or pdo tutorial

Comment: Have you execute this query by the function `mysql_query();`

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Answer (score 1):

The error is on this line,

```
UPDATE 'widget_corp' . 'subjects' SET
```

identifiers (*this includes column names and table names*) shouldn't be wrapped with single quotes. If happens that an identifier is a reserve keyword, it can be escape with backticks, not with single quotes.

In this case remove the single quotes and it will work.

Additional Links that will help you give more details,

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)
- [MySQL - when to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/mysql-when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: Thanks for the input but now i'm thinking the query is not the problem but somewhere before, cuz it's still working